# NuxtJS Installation with NPM - Why so many deprecated packages?

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, deprecated, deprecation-warning

Hi I'm creating my first NuxtJS app but while creating it I see many deprecation warnings by NPM. I know this won't stop my app from running but I'm just wondering why so many deprecated packages out-of-the-box here...

Can someone explain me what is going on? Some of the warnings are also pretty scary if you're just starting a new project such as security concerns and packages no longer maintained...

[image]

Comment: when there are almost 1400 dependency packages not owned or managed by nuxt, some may get depreciated over time, they cant simply be removed or swapped out.

Comment: could this lead to any security or other kind of concern?

Comment: sure, nuxt and its packages, like other frameworks/tools have security updates. Generally, you would use a 3rd party and hook it into your VCS if you're really concerned, and your be notified to update or bump versions etc, like github does it if you have a package.json in root folder.. most of the time its prototype pollution fixes

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you wanna explain it in an answer?

Comment: what a nightmare with nuxt generate .